# How to compare pixels in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have two textures in three.js that I would like to compare at pixel level. But I have no idea of how to do it. Three.js documentation does not answer my question. Indeed some of the classes are undocumented.

To be concise I want to compute how  different 2 images are (to calculate fitness value in my genetic algorithm).

Edit: I have been told that I should provide more information. Here we go.

One texture is from a image which is loaded using "loadTexture":

```
        referenceTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/tia1.jpg'); //256px*256px image
```

The get the other one I add some polygons to a second scene and later on I render that scene into a texture:

```
var bufferScene = new THREE.Scene();
var bufferTexture = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, { minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter,format: THREE.RGBAFormat});
bufferScene.add(triangle) //This is a bucle in the real code.
renderer.setSize(256,256);
requestAnimationFrame( render );
renderer.render(bufferScene, camera, bufferTexture);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is a bit too generic to allow precises answer. It would help if you had and minimal example code what you are trying to do. Without the code or specific API interfaces names it is hard to guess what part of Three.js API you are asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach each texture to a render target, then call `renderer.readRenderTargetPixels` to get the pixels out for each texture and then compare.

OR

You could render both textures to another render target using a shader that diffs the 2 textures and then read the pixels out of that render target using `renderer.readRenderTargetPixels`

Comment: Thank you. I think I am going to try the first option because shaders are complicated. Are both approaches equally good or the second one will be faster?

Answer (score 1):

You could draw texture on canvas of same size as texture and read pixels color from framebuffer with [gl.readPixels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/readPixels). After that you could compare values at CPU.

Also you could perform subtraction of pixel colors at GPU and render difference (and then readPixels).

Comment: I can't draw a canvas because I need to show both textures in the screen.